# Excel INDEX MATCH to find specific text in column then return the ladder cell reference

Tags: excel, search, indexing, spreadsheet

I have a specific question.

I have data in column C and column AR on one sheet and in another sheet have the search text in column C and the returned value in column E.

All other columns beside `Sheet1!AR` have only one type of info. Column AR have several numbers divided by a comma and a space. e.g.: `0101, 2020, 0303 etc.`

If e.g. 2020 is found in a cell in `Sheet1!AR` the value in `Sheet1!C` should be returned to `Sheet2!E`.

I have tried with below code without success.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(sheet1!$C$6:$C$15000,SMALL(IF(TRIM(sheet1!$AR$6:$AR$15000)=TRIM(Sheet2!C3),ROW(sheet1!$AR$6:$AR$15000)-ROW(sheet1!$AR$6)+1),ROW('DO NOT DELETE'!1:1))),"")
```

What the code also does is that it hides (or stops) when there is no more rows have the desired value (this have to be part of the code and it works)

The code works fine if the cell in `Sheet1!AR` only have one line of numbers.

---

In column `Sheet1!AR` i have several numbers divided by a comma and a space e.g.: `0101, 2020, 0303 etc.`. These numbers can differ but same number can be in more than one cell, so one cell can contain 6 numbers and another can contain only 1. In column `Sheet1!C`i have unique values that i want to return to Sheet2 if the chosen number exist in column `Sheet1!AR`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need an array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(sheet1!$C$6:$C$15000,MATCH("*" & TRIM(Sheet2!C3) & "*",sheet1!$AR:$AR,0))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This just return what is in `Sheet1!C:C` in what seems randomly. I had to specify rows in column AR before it would work otherwise it kept return one value from `Sheet1!C:C`.